# Drupal taxonomy problem

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I had setup my new [articles directory site](http://www.articlesdirectoryindia.com) in Drupal 6.2 2-3 months back. You can see the article directory taxonomy in the menu block in the left side bar.
There are 26 categories in total like "Financial services, Food & Bevereges" etc. And each category has sub categories.

The problem is that frequently some categories or sub categories get automatically unchecked in the article directory menu bar. So I need to regularly count them and check them on if unchecked.

For example today I found automatically unchecked as shown in the following image which is screen shot at the path: admin/build/menu-customize/menu-articledirectory:

[image]

**I'm wondering why this could be happening. Any idea?**

Comment: Which module are you using to create menu items against terms?

Comment: I'm using Taxonomy Menu and Menu Block

Comment: Looks like this problem is listed here: http://drupal.org/node/1206606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) then definitely there is a bug in it. And here is a the [Link](http://drupal.org/node/758198#comment-3094036) to define the reason.